# How to execute code once only when an RFID card is present or not

Tags: arduino, rfid

My code is super simple, but I'm at a loss how to do a simple task.

Each time an RFID card is read, I want it to trigger an event once. This is working fine in isolation.

However, I also want a different one-time event to occur each time a card is taken away. This bit seems to mess up the whole thing.

I'm using the MFRC522 Library.

Could anyone tell me the method to do both within the same code? I'm kind of green as to all this.

Many thanks in advance :) My code is here:

```
#include <MFRC522.h> 
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

bool executed = false;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);   // Initiate a serial communication    
  SPI.begin();      // Initiate  SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
}


void loop() { 

  if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {    
    if ( mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      Serial.println("Great!.. each time a card is read and re-read this text will print *ONCE ONLY*");
    }     
  } 

// BELOW I WANT TO EXECUTE A COMMAND *ONCE ONLY* EACH TIME A CARD IS TAKEN AWAY
// WHEN UNCOMMENTED, THE "Oh dear.." PRINTS CONTINUOUSLY 

//  if ( !mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {  
//    Serial.println("Oh dear... this seems to keep printing... ");  
//  }

  mfrc522.PICC_HaltA();          // Halt PICC
  mfrc522.PCD_StopCrypto1();     // Stop encryption on PCD  
}
```

Also, the revised code that I also tried is as follows. This also did not work. It printed the card present fine but when the card was taken away multiple prints continuously occured:

```
    #include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define RST_PIN    9
#define SS_PIN    10

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create MFRC522 instance

bool executed = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initialize serial communications with the PC
  SPI.begin(); // Init SPI bus
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); // Init MFRC522
  Serial.println("Waiting for RFID-chip...");
}

void loop() {
  if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {    
    if ( mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
      Serial.println("Great!.. each time a card is read and re-read this text will print *ONCE ONLY*");
      executed = true;
    }     
  } 
  else {  
    if (executed) {
      Serial.println("Oh dear... this seems to keep printing... ");  
      executed = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps instead of having 2 *if* stamenents, you can combine them into an *if-else* statement. You also want to use the variable `executed` you created at the top inside your conditionals.

Here is how I see it:

```
if ( mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {    
  if ( mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
    Serial.println("Great!.. each time a card is read and re-read this text will print *ONCE ONLY*");
    executed = true;
  }     
} 
else {  
  if (executed) {
    Serial.println("Oh dear... this seems to keep printing... ");  
    executed = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. This is certainly a step in the right direction. The card present ("Great!... each time a...") does indeed only print once. However, when the card is taken away "Oh dear...." still prints continuously.

Comment: Are you sure you included the 'if (executed)' part in your code right before Serial.println("oh dear...")? That should print the "oh dear" if `executed == true`, but it is immediately set to false after it prints and thus locks itself from printing again

Comment: Yes, I indeed made sure that I included that part. Here's the full code:

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to post code in my replies to you... so I posted the full code with your suggested code included in my original question at the bottom :)

Comment: maybe you can do a serial print of `executed` in a few places to see what value it has, as well as printing debug stuff in other places to see if you can trace the flow of your program. Just by looking your code right now I can't see anything obviously wrong, sadly, so you'll have to do some dirty work yourself

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution using "CurrentCard" as variable to store te current card UID and "CardTimeOut" as time limit variable to reset the stored UID when you leave the card.
Hope this helps you!

```
String CurrentCard;    
int CardTimeOut = 0;

void loop {
      // Look for new cards
      if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) 
      {
        CardTimeOut = 0;
        if (mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) 
        {
          String content= "";
          for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) 
          {
             content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
             content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
          }
          content.toUpperCase();

          if (content.substring(1) != CurrentCard)
          {
            if (content.substring(1) == "D7 48 35 4B") //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
            {
              Serial.println("Authorized access");
              Serial.println();
              //Do something
            }
            else
            {
              Serial.println(" Access denied");
            }
            CurrentCard = content.substring(1);
          }
        }
      }
      if (CardTimeOut > 10)
      {
        CurrentCard = "";
      }
      CardTimeOut += 1;
    }
```